# How to create SQL account that can only perform certain actions?

Tags: security, sql-server, sql

I'm used to working on contracts where someone else is responsible for the SQL database.  However, I'm now working a contract where I must set up a new SQL Server, so I set up MS SQL Server 2012 Express.

I've written an application that connects to the SQL server and reads/updates several tables.  In my test environment, the application is connecting using the sa account, which is, of course, a big no-no.

I want to create a user account that will be able to select/insert/update/delete from a limited set of tables and have no other privileges what-so-ever.

I would follow along with some of the instructions that I see on Google, but I keep seeing questions regarding unprivileged accounts unexpectedly having the right to do things that the account creator didn't intend, so I wanted to ask the experts:

How do I create a SQL account that can only do one thing: select/insert/update/delete from a limited set of tables?

**Edit:** Based on the feedback I've received, I did some research and wrote the following script:

```
CREATE LOGIN ExtraUser
    WITH PASSWORD = 'foobar';

USE MyDatabase;

CREATE USER ExtraUser FOR LOGIN ExtraUser;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.abc;
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.def;
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.def;
```

This appears to do what I want, but I would like to know if I can trust that this user can't access anything other than the two tables to which I've given him access.

Comment: To start, you will need to create an account that has datareader and datawriter roles.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Adding the user to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` indeed grants global read/write access to the database.

You will need to use `GRANT` to grant access to the login for specific objects.

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table1 TO ExtraUser
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.Table1 TO ExtraUser
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.Table1 TO ExtraUser
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.Table1 TO ExtraUser
```

You can also combine the permissions as necessary:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE on dbo.Table1 to ExtraUser
```

Note: you will need to run that for each table you wish to allow access to

More information on `GRANT` can be found [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx).

**EDIT:**
In response to your edit, yes.  It will restrict that user to those permissions, so long as you have not also granted something more overpowering (like adding the login to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`).  If you have, then you should revoke those higher level permissions using [**`REVOKE`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187719.aspx).